# MySql select statement (select distinct) issues

Tags: mysql, select

So I have a schema that goes something like this

Historical  -- Table
--CID
--ID
--LOCATION
--STATUS
--TIME

CID doesn't matter for this, but I do want to get the 1 oldest TIME (TimeStamp) for each ID

So what I'm trying to do is something like

`SELECT DISTINCT(id) from Historical order by TIME asc limit 1`  But where I get each ID, and the oldest time for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT id, min(time) FROM Historical GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, MIN(TIME) FROM Historical GROUP BY id;
```

This will select distinct IDs (by grouping) and the MIN TIME for each grouped ID.